# What is the issue in this create view

Tags: sql, hive

```
CREATE VIEW TRIPS AS 
(SELECT * 
FROM bike_trips201402 UNION 
SELECT * FROM 
bike_trips201408 UNION 
SELECT * FROM bike_trips2015);
```

When I run the above in Hive editor in Hadoop, it gives `ParseException`

Comment: make sure that selected table schemas are compatible to each other in order to use them with `UNION` clause.

Comment: the 3 tables are having the same schema with data sets at different points of time

Comment: Are the column names for the 3 tables the same?

Comment: why do you have it in parenthesis?

Comment: One problem is that you're using `SELECT *`. That may not be the cause for your error (precisely), but it's certainly a problem regardless. Never use `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW TRIPS AS 
SELECT * 
FROM bike_trips201402 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM 
bike_trips201408 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM bike_trips2015;
```

You need to put ALL keywords as its seem to be reserved keywords..